# Installing/configuring gdbm Python module for cvs2svn?

Tags: python, solaris, cvs2svn, gdbm

I am trying to install cvs2svn on a Solaris 10 machine. It has Python 2.4.4 on it. I don't have root access. When I downloaded cvs2svn and tried to run it, it said

> ERROR: cvs2svn uses the anydbm package, which depends on lower level dbm libraries. Your system has dbm, with which cvs2svn is known to have problems. To use cvs2svn, you must install a Python dbm library other than dumbdbm or dbm. See http://python.org/doc/current/lib/module-anydbm.html for more information.

I downloaded gdbm, compiled, and installed it in my home directory. How do I get a Python gdbm module installed that works with anydbm? Google isn't helping...

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded Python 2.5.1 and compiled it from the source. I made sure my gdbm libraries were in the appropriate paths and used the altinstall into my home directory. I can now run cvs2svn with my private copy of python.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to the location where you installed `gdbm`.  Then when you run `cvs2svn`, the anybdm module should find `gdbm` successfully.

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. Could this be part of it?

ls -l /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/*db*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     bin        12176 Jan 31  2007 /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/dbm.so*

Comment: Firstly, I think the solution you settled on is the most bulletproof.  On the other hand, I'm not sure how to interpret your comment exactly. I think you're suggesting that dbm is found and therefore gdbm is ignored. Check the source for anydbm...  will it look for dbm or gdbm first?  If dbm first, then I guess my original answer is wrong.  I think cvs2svn should really include logic to deal with this properly!  Requiring that you DON'T have dbm installed is not nice.

Comment: cvs2svn *does* go to contortions to try to choose a decent database backend for anydbm; see http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/source/browse/cvs2svn/trunk/cvs2svn_lib/database.py?view=markup for the hairy details.

Answer (score 0):

To install gdbm for Python, try:

```
pip install gdbm
```

If `pip` is not present, install it via: `easy_install pip`.

On OSX, you may try (if `brew` is installed):

```
brew install gdbm
```