# Alternative to cvs2svn for performing cvs to svn migration

Tags: python, macos, xserver, cvs2svn, gdbm

I am trying to perform a migration from cvs to svn on my our new XServe server which is running OS X Server.  There is a known conflict between the cvs2svn and dbm libraries that come pre-installed with OS X.  The error is:

> ERROR: cvs2svn uses the anydbm package, which depends on lower level dbm libraries. Your system has dbm, with which cvs2svn is known to have problems. To use cvs2svn, you must install a Python dbm library other than dumbdbm or dbm. See http://python.org/doc/current/lib/module-anydbm.html for more information.

I followed all the prescribed steps in the [cvs2svn FAQ](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#osxsetup) but the error still persists.  Does anyone know of an alternative way to accomplish this task, or another website that offer a different solution to this seemingly common problem?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922750

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since CVS and Subversion repositories are really just collections of files, one way to work around this problem might be to copy your CVS repository to a machine where cvs2svn can run successfully, run it to convert to Subversion, and then copy the new repository back to your server. The added benefit of this method is that you won't run the risk of accidentally messing up your server configuration while doing this conversion step.

Answer (score 3):

cvs2svn itself is available in MacPorts so, instead of just the dbm libraries, you could install cvs2svn using MacPorts:

```
port install cvs2svn
```

If not already installed, it will also install the MacPorts version of python2.5 and other dependencies.  There's no harm in that but it will take a little time and a little extra space.  The advantage is that you should have a working, supported version without having to fight further dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could always manually install other dbm libraries using e.g. MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have subversion installed , Did you make sure that the path is set right in your system variables?

I had that same issue on mine and I ended up having to add the variables in Python_Home and path to use

C:\Pyton27\

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sounds a bit crazy or overkill, but think about using 'git' (e.g. MacPorts version). It clones the complete CVS history and pushes it into a Subversion repository. The following steps should do the work (look at the command's manuals, git help ´cmd´):

```
    port install git-core cvs cvsps svn (if necessary)

    create directory for git and init cvs git repo (let´s say ´cd ~/cvsgit´):
    git cvsimport -v -d CVSROOT module

    create new subversion repository (svnadmin) with trunk, tags, branches
    now import this new repository to a git repository:
    git svn clone -s file:///path/to/svnrepo  (without trunk, tags, branches)
    this creates a svnrepo directory; rename and move it to e.g. ~/svngit

    now add the cvs git repo to svn repo:
    cd ~/svngit
    git remote add cvsrepo ~/cvsgit
    git fetch cvsrepo

    now merge the cvs master branch to the local svn master branch:
    git merge remotes/cvsrepo/master

    finally commit to (real) svn repository:
    git svn dcommit
```

You're done!

Comment: But please beware that git-cvsimport is known to have serious problems converting all but the most trivial CVS repositories: http://marc.info/?l=git&m=123626637729412&w=2

Comment: mtp: Please supply specifics (and bug reports!) to back up your complaint about cvs2svn.  (Disclaimer: I take it a bit personally since I'm the cvs2svn maintainer.)